# onedrive startup application not starting up but works in terminal

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, startup-applications

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.  I installed onedrive and did all the authorisation stuff and it works fine when I run it from the terminal.

I ran startup applications and used `onedrive --monitor` as I would in the terminal but it fails to run on boot.  The program is in my usr/bin folder and I tried putting the whole path. Nope.  I also tried just running onedrive without the `--monitor`. Nope.

Preferably I'd also like it to relaunch automatically if it fails.  I'm wondering can it be run as a service?  Not sure what's going on.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I installed it with 

sudo apt install onedrive

It's working fine.  When I run it manually from the terminal, it syncs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#running-onedrive-as-a-system-service to run the client as a service automatically at startup.

Doing this in the manner you are attempting, will cause the application to not start in the manner you are expecting.

Also, installing via 'sudo apt install onedrive' is not recommended. This installs an old and unsupported version. Please either use the Ubuntu PPA or compile from source.